# Within a category, how can I get the apps in Xfce 4.14's Whisker Menu to sort alphabetically?

Tags: sorting, xfce, xubuntu, ubuntu-20.04, xfce4

Whenever I install a new program and it gets placed in a category on the Whisker Menu (e.g. "Education", "Development"), it always defaults to putting the program at the bottom of the categories that it goes in to. How can I make this default to alphabetical sorting?

MenuLibre, the tool used for editing these menus, has a button for sorting individual categories alphabetically, but this isn't a persistent setting - it's a one-off sort that has to be repeated for every new app and every category that it goes in to.

Note: I've seen some [similar questions](https://askubuntu.com/q/779469/824054) on AskUbuntu, but the situation appears to have changed since version 4.12.

Answer (score 0):

**Possible solution**:

1. https://classicforum.manjaro.org/index.php?PHPSESSID=2eqq3rhlb8dgtc49t82unqn151&topic=19686.msg178794#msg178794
   "Do this: right-click on the panel, navigate to Panel > Panel Preferences..., then change to the Items tab, and select the Window Buttons item. Click the settings button, and in the dialog that opens, change the Sorting order dropdown menu to "Timestamp"."

**Related**:

1. https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=11791

Comment: I see no reason why this setting should matter. That setting is for the order of windows on your panel. This is, it controls stuff like "if both Firefox and Chrome are open, what order should they appear in?".

Comment: @J.Mini - I am simply reproducing what others experimented and posted. At any rate, it costs nothing to check that.

Comment: @J.Mini - Did this work for you?

Comment: I never tested it. It's not the solution that I wanted, but I'll keep it in mind whenever I next install something.

Comment: Finally tried this. I don't know if it works, but I simply find its side effects unbearable. Not being able to re-order windows is an insane limitation.